# compatibility between xml and emf model in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

For my project I'm having an emf model. The model is populated from data that I'm getting from backend as a rest response which is xml. I need to change the backend response to add a new attribute to an element. Now the emf model is throwing compatibility error saying that the new attribute is not found. Is there any way to make the emf model compatible with the new rest xml response. Means to say the emf model should ignore the xml's new attribute and fill the rest of the things. It is because I want to provide support for the old clients also.

Comment: Why cant you evolve the emf meta model? Adding a new attribute does not involve any migration strategies as it is a compatible change. What do you mean with "old clients"?

Answer (score 0):

If you add new attributes to your model and make them optional, i.e. lowerbound=0, it should work.